# Adding all text in one column from different rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, text-mining, data-cleaning

I have a data frame with 2 columns. First column is the student's ID and the second column is the student's opinion about the exam. The student might have one row or more about the exam. How can I add all the text from each student into one row for each student?
In the picture, we have 3 students. First student expressed his opinion in 3 rows. How can I make his opinion in one row.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apg4Y.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO and congrats on your first question. Do read the guideline on how to psot questions. As a rule, post a sample of your data and not a screenshot. It makes it very tedious for anyone wishing to help you to do so. Also, try to share your own personal attemps at solving the problem.

Comment: @Fadi please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use newline as the separator:

```
df.groupby('student ID')['Transcript'].apply(lambda t: '\n'.join(t))
```

You will see several `\n` characters when you preview the data frame in IPython or Jupyter, but they are just indicator of the actual newline character and not the literal slash-n (`\n`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.agg('. '.join)` if you are trying to join the different lines into one line as multiple sentences:

```
print(df)
In[1]: 
   student ID Transcript
0      101010          A
1      101010          B
2      101010          C
3      202020          A
4      202020          B
5      303030          A
6      303030          B
```

---

```
df.groupby('student ID')['Transcript'].agg('. '.join).reset_index()

Out[1]: 
   student ID Transcript
0      101010    A. B. C
1      202020       A. B
2      303030       A. B
```